# Template Method: How to use it when you want to be able to flexibly change primitive options?

Tags: java, design-patterns, code-duplication, strategy-pattern, template-method-pattern

The problem is best explained with the following code:

```
public class TemplateClass {
    public void templateOne() {
        checkConditionA();
        primitiveOp1();
        checkConditionB();
    }

    public void templateTwo() {
        checkConditionA();
        primitiveOp2();
        checkConditionB();
    }

    protected abstract void primitiveOp1();
    protected abstract void primitiveOp2();
    // rest of the methods
}
```

Now I have code duplication with templateOne() and templateTwo(), but I would like to have just one template method but with interchangeable primitive operations.

Comment: You could pass the `primitiveOperation` as an argument to the method.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is, in essence, a guard block around a method call. [DRY programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) is good practice, but be advice that you do not wawnt to couple what should not be coupled. I would only couple those two methods if it is guaranteed that they must always be guarded by the same pre- and postcondition(s).

If this is the case, I would recommend to implement a method `private void callWithChecks(Runnable primitiveOperation)` and then pass the respective primitive operation as parameter to this method:

```
public abstract class TemplateClass {
    public void templateOne() {
        callWithChecks(this::primitiveOp1);
    }

    public void templateTwo() {
        callWithChecks(this::primitiveOp2);
    }

    private void callWithCkecks(Runnable primitiveOperation) {
        checkConditionA();
        primitiveOperation.run();
        checkConditionB();
    }

    protected abstract void primitiveOp1();
    protected abstract void primitiveOp2();
    // rest of the methods
}
```

If you do not want to use the function interface `Runnable`, you can of course define your own interface. I went with it, since it is a Java base class.

---

Two remarks on your code:

- `TempalteClass` must be declared `abstract`, otherwise the code will not compile
- If you intend to implement methods `checkConditionA()` and `checkConditionB()` within `TemplateClass`, I would recommend defining them as `private` or `final` such that they cannot be overridden.